# Any simple concrete proof of Faltings theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-geometry

Are there simple proofs of some concrete special cases of [Faltings's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you would like to see a simple proof of some special case of Faltings's theorem (which is not what you wrote).

Comment: @GHfromMO right, right, you are right, thank you for explanation

Comment: I updated your question, I hope it is ok.

Comment: this might be what you are looking for: https://mathoverflow.net/a/202800/11260

Comment: @GH I guess one could call that "Faltings theorem". But even just in his famous *Inventiones* paper, there are three famous theorems, previously known as the *Isogeny Conjecture*, the *Shafarevich Conjecture*, and the *Mordell Conjecture*, any of which could now be called *Faltings Theorem*. Not to mention his generalization of the latter to a proof of *Lang's Conjecutre* concerning rational points on subvarieties of abelian varieties.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: It is not my question, I just improved the formulation at some other points. Feel free to update! Also, please take note of the link which should disambiguate.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Vojta's proof (especially the Bombieri simplification) is definitely more elementary than Faltings original proof, but it is still not simple, and it covers the full theorem. I think that the OP wants, say, a single curve $C$ for which there is a simple proof that $C(K)$ is finite for all number fields $K$. In fact, before Faltings work, there were no such examples proven. OTOH, if the OP just wants some curves $C/\mathbb Q$ for which it is possible to prove, in a relatively easy way, that $C(\mathbb Q)$ is finite, that can be done, e.g., by the method of Dem'janenko.

Comment: Thank everyone for your comment, a special case which keep the outline or the approach of Faltings proof is better.

Comment: For the modular curve I wonder if there is a way using the kind of methods involved in [CM points](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/91/KaYui91.pdf).

Comment: https://youtu.be/8fEMcuX3LgQ there is part of Faltings's theorem as a example in the lecture, but actually is not proof, and I am not sure whether she follows the approach of Faltings.

Comment: Here’s a liar’s proof: write down D := D_{a,b,c} := N * (a * \Delta + b * H + c * V), where \Delta is the diagonal in C x C, H := C x {pt} and V := {pt} x C. D is effective, so h_D\geq 0. We’d like sections of D, so let’s make D ample. By Riemann-Roch for surfaces, it suffices to make D.D gigantic. Actually for intersection calculations it’s better to replace \Delta by \Delta’ := \Delta - H - V, so that \Delta’.\Delta’ = -2g. [Note that H.V = 1, H.H = V.V = \Delta’.H = \Delta’.V = 0.] So the self intersection of D (replacing \Delta by \Delta’ in the definition) is N^2 * (-2g a^2 + 2bc).

Comment: So when N is gigantic, the self intersection is big so long as bc > 2g a^2. On the other hand, Mumford calculated the height with respect to \Delta’. It’s h’(x,y) = -<x,y> (here I’m thinking of the points in Euclidean space using the canonical height as ||.||^2). The heights wrt H and V are just h_H(x,y) = ||x||^2/2g and h_V(x,y) = ||y||^2/2g, respectively. [I always get these constants wrong by an overall factor: this is not the lie.] So h_D(x,y) is just N * (-2g a * <x,y> + b * ||x||^2 + c * ||y||^2). Let’s try to make this quadratic form in x and y negative to optimize our h_D\geq 0.

Comment: It can be made negative when the discriminant N^2 * ((2ga)^2 - 4bc) = 4N^2 (g^2 a^2 - bc) > 0. So we need the conditions ga^2 < bc and g^2 a^2 > bc. There is room to satisfy these inequalities when g > 1. Now just minimize the quadratic form: take a := 1, b := t * ||x|| / ||y||, and c := t * ||y|| / ||x||, with g < t^2 < g^2. Then h_D(x,y) is N * (-2g <x,y> + 2t ||x|| ||y||)\geq 0. Hence if x and y are rational points on C they must have cosine of the angle between them at most t/g. Taking t ~ \sqrt{g} gives Vojta’s inequality. Project C(K) to the unit sphere of J(K)\otimes_\Z \R.

Comment: Then any two projections must have angle between them at least some nonzero constant (this proves injectivity), hence nontrivial spherical distance between them, hence sufficiently small spherical caps contain at most one rational point. By compactness there are finitely many spherical caps, done. Where was the lie? [Once you find it you’ll see why Vojta has to use Roth, and also why Vojta’s inequality has a “skewness” condition. Also I didn’t resurrect the question! :) Also I forgot a factor of 1/(2g) outside in my expressions for h_D, but it’s immaterial.]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on the OP's comment clarifying his question, I fear that the answer is no, there are no concrete special cases in which one can follow the approach of Faltings' proof that yield any significant simplifications. Faltings' proof is very indirect. First one uses rational points in $C(K)$ to construct coverings of $C$ that have good reduction outside a certain finite set of primes $S$. (This idea is, I believe, due to Parshin.) Taking Jacobians yields abelian varieties with good reduction outside $S$. One can, in principle, do this for a specific curve fairly concretely. But now one is reduced to Faltings proof of the Shafarevich conjecture, that there are only finitely many (suffices to do principally polarized) abelian varieties of a given dimension having good reduction outside $S$. And the proof of that is via reversing an argument of Tate to show it suffices to prove the isogeny conjecture, which gives a Galois-theoretic interpretation of isogenies between abelian varieties. And the proof of the isogeny conjecture is sufficiently complicated that I won't try to summarize it here. Anyway, bottom line is it does not appear that applying Faltings' ideas to a single curve would simplify the argument very much.

Having said that, there are more elementary methods that can prove that is $C(K)$ finite in some cases. There's the method of **Dem'janenko**: If there are independent maps $f_1,...,f_n:C\to E$ for some elliptic curve $E$, and if $n>\text{rank } E(K)$, then $C(K)$ is finite. This is done via a height calculation. It was generalized by Manin, who applied it to towers of modular curves $X_1(p^k)$. There is the method of **Chabauty** (strengthened to what is now usually called the **Chabauty-Coleman method**): Let $C/K$ and $J=\text{Jac}(C)$. If $\text{genus}(C)>\text{rank }J(K)$, then $C(K)$ is finite. The proof is via $p$-adic analytic methods. Coleman made the method quite precise (using *Coleman integration*), so in many cases it allows one to actually compute $C(K)$. Note that Faltings original proof, and the Vojta-Bombieri-Faltings alternative proof via Diophantine approximation, are ineffective.

Answer (score 4):

Recently [Lawrence and Venkatesh gave a proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02721.pdf) that uses Faltings' setup but looks at variation of p-adic Galois representations in a family of algebraic varieties. Neither simpler nor a concrete special case, though.

Comment: If it's neither simpler not a concrete special case, how is this an answer? This would make a fine comment, but not an answer on its own

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks